# Group 2 AND statement in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to develop a messaging system in php and mysql, and I want to retrieve all the messages between 2 people by using the following query:

```
 $message = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM messages WHERE (sentby=$id AND sentto=$id2)AND (sentby=$id2 AND sentto=$id) ORDER BY time DESC");
```

This sql statement is not working. I think it's because the AND statement between (sentby=$id2 AND sentto=$id) and (sentby=$id AND sentto=$id2) it's not the correct syntax. Can someone show the the proper way of writing this query?

Thank you guys, changing it to OR solved my problem. Originally I have it as OR but since after this query, I have another query that search for the username associated with the user ID, and I found out that if I use OR it will give usernames of both people. Getting confused and tired, I changed it to AND to try to solve the problem. Now I have both my problems fixed.

Comment: You want `OR` instead of `AND` here- `(sentby=$id AND sentto=$id2) OR (sentby=$id2 AND sentto=$id)`

Comment: Also tag only the database you are using. Which one is it? MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE (sentby=$id OR sentby=$id2) AND (sentto=$id2 OR sentto=$id)
```

this will say select all where sentby = either id, and also sentto has to = either ID

```
$message = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM messages WHERE (sentby=$id OR sentby=$id2) AND (sentto=$id2 OR sentto=$id) ORDER BY time DESC");
```